# SVN hooks. Is there such thing as post-update server side hook?

Tags: svn, svn-hooks, post-update

I want to enforce policy, when one should always update before commit. Generally I like the idea of doing this with server side set of hooks to guarantee that unmatched commit will be prevented.

In order to know, when was the last update and last commit for a particular user, I have to track both commits and updates on server. It's ok with post-commit, but I just can't find a way to add server side post-update hook. No problem with client side though, but I don't want to rely on clients setup with that check.

It there a server side post-update hook, or update event is always processed solely by client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post-update hooks doesn't exist in Subversion, but they aren't needed in your case:

- There aren't reasons to require update WC in the case of missing intersection between files in transaction and changed by earlier commits, not existing in WC
- If such intersection exist, commit will be blocked automatically and developer must update and merge foreign changes before own commit

Comment: This doesn't work quite well, when several people work on interacting parts. Each part may be separated in own module, so there will be no interaction between files, but interfaces of these modules may change. These changes being unnoticed might lead to completely broken revision. It is best to have the complete project first tested locally, then commited.